# Validating string date without using java.util.Date class in Java

Tags: java

This question was ask me in one of interview "How can we validate *(Valid or invalid)* string date in java without using java.util.date class.Dateformat could be in any form i.e. **dd-MM-yyyy,yyyy-dd-MM and so on.**".Please help if anyone have idea.TIA

Comment: use DateFormat for parse the date string into Date object?

Comment: "Date can be in any format". What does that even mean? "Bathsheba's birthday" is a valid date, and that's a date format.

Comment: "simple" + "without using any libraries" + "handle hundreds of possible formats"... Good luck with that!

Comment: @Nikhil Kshirsagar You can ask the user which format he is inputting in eg: dd/mm/yyyy, or dd [month in name] yyyy, and then use the necessary regex to extract the date.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without libraries? Why reinvent the wheel if you don't have to? Please see: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Also, this is kind of "gimme teh codez" as written. Can you show what you've tried so far and be more specific?

Comment: @Bathsheba - Sorry for posting unclear question.I hope its clear now.

Comment: @EJoshuaS : Thanks for posting comment.I told solution of  parsing string and checking for each date format. But I just wanted to know if there is some intelligent way to do that because my solution was not much optimal in terms of performance and memory.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to parse java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate then you have a standard yyyy-mm-dd. this should be easy to validate. Can you identify the source of your date object? If you can obtain a calendar object fro you source or from the date object then this method I wrote should help with the parsing.

```
/**
 *  Utility method that parses java.util.Date to java 8's java.time.LocalDat
 * <p>
 * TODO finish method design
 *
 * @param calendarObj
 * @return
 */
public static LocalDate parseCalendarToLocalDate(Calendar calendarObj) {

    int month = calendarObj.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = calendarObj.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int day = calendarObj.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    LocalDate localDateObj =  LocalDate.of(year,(month+1),day);
    return localDateObj;
}
```